# GWT: extract textarea value using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, tampermonkey

**Context**: I'm working on a tampermonkey script to enrich some GWT pages witnin a 3rd party app, no access to sourcecode nor to servers

**Problem**: I need to extract the value of a textarea element using plain JavaScript (see above as to why)

**HTML as I see now**: inside a series of table>tr>td>div>div>div

```
<textarea class="gwt-TextArea" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;" id="MyTarget"></textarea>
```

**issue**:

- the html of the textarea does NOT contain any text, what I see must be something else
- as expected document.getElementById("MyTarget").value==""

Answer (score 0):

Value is the property you want and should work without any problems.

Here is a quick example showing how to use it.

```js
document.getElementById('MyTarget').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  let value = document.getElementById('MyTarget').value;
  document.getElementById('MyOutput').innerHTML = value;
})
```

```html
<textarea class="gwt-TextArea" style="height: 100px; width: 200px;" id="MyTarget" onkeyup="window.keyup"></textarea>
<div id="MyOutput">

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, tried multiple variantes without success. In my scenario .value==""